# Magento 2 Knockout JS - What does this._super() do?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, requirejs, knockoutjs

Whilst researching Magento 2's implementation of Knockout JS I keep coming across `this._super();`.

What does this do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Searching the dev docs for this returns the [uiClass library page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_uiclass_concept.html) which mentions the following:

> The _super() method calls the parent UI component method with the same name as the _super() method’s caller; if that method does not exists in the parent UI component, then the method tries to find it higher in the inheritance chain.

The below example would call the parent methods initialize function.

```
initialize: function () {
    this._super(); //_super will call parent's `initialize` method here

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Look up the prototype js library. That's what magento uses to implement this functionality.

Comment: You always know the answer @ben